# How to report about how many users have registered in a given timeframe?

Tags: 7, users, log-messages

We want to know how many users registered to our website as a report.

I'm looking for a way (or a solution) in D7 that allows me to give me a report of how many user have registered to my website. Ideally will show me how many user register yesterday, weekly, monthly and annual.

Comment: Have you tried to do this with views and [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)?

Comment: Yes, @J.Reynolds right. Reynolds, I think you can post this as an answer :)

Comment: I think that it is possible to do this using VIEWS. I will try it and tell you if I succeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some modules to consider, for anybody who is not able or willing to write some PHP coding to answer such typical reporting question (or anybody who does not want to enable the PHP filter in a site):

1. The [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module can be used for such types of reporting. It comes with all sorts of [Sample reports and solutions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360173), such as the *Site administration reports*, which contain data about the actual Drupal site. Here are some details about those reports:

   - **Active Users** - A variation of D7's admin/people, including hyperlinks to the Logs for User report.
   - **Active Users Email** - A demo of the ability to send email to all active users of a drupal site.
   - **Logs for User** - Most recent watchdog log entries for a user (specified as a report parameter).
   - **Role Details** - A table displaying all users for a Drupal role (specified as a report parameter), and the Drupal permissions granted to them, with for each user hyperlinks to either view or edit the user's profile.

   Cloning these sample reports into custom variations is straight forward. E.g. tune the **active users** report with some report parameters to only report about user registered this week.
2. For somebody looking for info related to visitors of a website (registered users is a subset of them, no?), the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module might be a valid alternative to consider also (and/or addition to the above module). Obviously, to submit a registration request one has to "visit" an URL like `user/register` (or something similar).

   The demo site contains [some sample reports (charts)](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors) available to anonymous users also. This demo site also shows some additional blocks with reports also created by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module module. Refer to the [Visitors community docu](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) for some more details.

   Extra reporting features can be enabled via these sub-modules:

   - The **Visitors GeoIP** module, to also report about countries and cities.
   - The **Visitors Browscap** module, providing statistics on visiting browsers.

Both modules also support charting of those data (a typical related requirement ...)

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena), and the maintainer of [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you searching for a module. You can create a block & add custom code.

1. Enable the PHP filter
2. Create a block
3. Add the following code

   ```
   $result= db_query("SELECT count(1) from {users}") -> fetchField();

   print '< ul > < li >' . $result . ' < /ul>''< /ul>';
   ```

Comment: Any possibility to somehow enhance this approach to also add an option to specify weekly, etc (as in the question)?