# User and Content tracking and analytics

Tags: nodes

I have a fairly active Drupal 7 environment and I would like to track and log certain things about my users and their behaviour.

What are some of the approaches people tend to take to this? Ideally I'd love to graph some kpi's for reporting etc.

For example I if wanted to track (and log for comparison) things like:

Number of new users this day/week/month
Number of new nodes of 'content type' created this day/week/month
Number of new comments this day/week/month
Most active users (not just in terms of content created but also number of logins, number of comments etc...)

On a per user basis I love to know things everything I can reasonably find about behaviour.

Danny.

Comment: Is this not something you could do with Views and an admin dashboard?

Comment: That's what I've been doing to date, I guess I was just wondering if there is a better way? Some module/web that I wasn't aware of that would give me lots of pretty graphs without too much hard work.

Additionally I'm wondering about things that aren't currently logged like number of logins etc. 

Is the standard approach to this kind of thing to add integer fields to the user account and use rules or similar to increment?

Answer (score 0):

For most part, you can achieve this using contrib modules. Here are some of them:

1. [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) will allow you to fetch most of the information in your database and create pages, blocks and subpages.
2. [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) will override default admin pages (e.g. `/admin/content/node` and `/admin/people`) and even more importantly, allow you to change the output of those pages.
3. [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) allows you to export information from Views to a variety of formats, from `txt` to `csv`.
4. [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) with custom
5. [Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/messages) module. I've used Messages module many times when I needed to track an action of a user somewhere. It integrates with Views and Rules, and in combination with the two you can log most actions on the site.
6. [Total Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_control) gives you a central administrative page from where you can manage different sections. It's also coming with certain panes that you might find useful.
7. [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) will allow you to create more complex pages that contain blocks and information in a different layout than what is provided by default in your admin theme (e.g. 3 columns and multiple different rows).
8. [Forena reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module allows you to create custom reports from the database.

For additional information, see [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/150184/8623) response by Pierre Vriens.

Lastly, I just realized that this question might not be really suited for this website as it's opinion based and asks for module suggestions. If that's the case, I guess mods will remove both the question and answer.